# Upload File to Flex web application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am trying to upload a file to my web based Flex application. However, all the research I'm doing only discusses uploading a file from a user to a web server destination.

Is there a way to upload a file to the app for processing? Or must it be uploaded to the server and processed there? (It is trivially easy to download content from a server.)

Comment: Flex apps live in the browser or desktop so you cant 'upload' to it - its local, not remote. Do you mean 'load a file from users system into the app'?

Comment: Apparently, yes. I kind realized that was the case this morning as I was showering. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way (except the variant with server upload/download) is to use [FileReference.load()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) method and the [FileReference.data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#data) property for file bytes processing. You should call this method after calling [FileReference.browse()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse%28%29) with standart browse dialog, where use will select the file.

Comment: This morning as I was showering it occurred to me that the FileReference.browse() command that the examples show are probably linked to something that would read in the data. Doh! Thanks.